# Enable SQL Server Authentication - DSN Configuration

Tags: sql-server, odbc, dsn

I'm using Powershell to update DSN configuration. Example code:

```
$properties = @('server=databaseServer1', 'description=Test description')
Set-OdbcDsn -Name 'TestDSN' -SetPropertyValue $properties -DsnType System
```

This works. I want to enable SQL Server Authentication, following this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-2017#authentication---sqlcoptssauthentication) I tried:

```
$properties = @('SqlPassword=SQL_AU_PASSWORD')
```

Does not work. Also tried:

```
$properties = @('Authentication=SqlPassword')
```

Does not work. Both show the error `Invalid keyword-value pairs.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set Trusted_Connection (No = SQL Server Authentication, Yes = Windows Authentication)

```
$properties = @('server=databaseServer1', 'description=Test description','Trusted_Connection=No')
Set-OdbcDsn -Name 'TestDSN' -SetPropertyValue $properties -DsnType System
```